# What is the best way to shred files on a SSD

Tags: ssd, file-shredding

I was about to shred files on a new Solid State Drive but the shredding app warned me it was not a good idea because it would be inefficient and would also reduce the lifespan of the drive.

Is there any way to shred files the harshest way possible on a SSD with out having to physically destroy it?

Thank you.

Comment: Interesting question.  You probably just need to overwrite once, not use a 7 or 21 pass, etc algorithm.  I havent heard of people being able to recover overwritten data from SSDs...

Comment: @Keltari it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

This has been covered on ServerFault [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/199672/secure-delete-on-ssd).

Doesn't look like there is a way to delete just one file with any degree of security. Wiping the drive completely seems to work ok. Of course, I believe the only way to destroy data is total, physical destruction.